# input string was not put correct format

Tags: c#

```
        if (Session["totalCost"] != null)
        {
             if (Session["totalCost"] != "confirm")
             {
                totRevenueLabel.Text = totalRevenueInteger.ToString();
                totalRevenueInteger += int.Parse(Session["totalCost"].ToString());
             }
```

however, when I executed the program, it said input string was not put a in correct format

please help!

Comment: totalRevenueInteger += int.Parse(Session["totalCost"].ToString());

Comment: i think 0 but im not sure

Answer (score 2):

Your are parsing

```
int.Parse(Session["totalCost"].ToString());
```

So it is supposed that `Session["totalCost"]` has a numeric value in a string format. But earlier you are doing:

```
if (Session["totalCost"] != "confirm")
```

which shows that `Session["totalCost"]` contains the alphabets in the string format. Both statements are opposite to each other. I hope now you can find your problem.

Comment: I think the code is implying if `["totalCost"]` does not equal `confirm` then it will be a number, so this logic seems fine to me as long as there is an additional check before parsing.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the string you're trying to parse an integer from doesn't actually contain a valid integer.

```
int i;
if(int.TryParse(Session["totalCost"].ToString(), out i)
{
   totalRevenueInteger = i;
}
```

Comment: so what should i do, please help!

Comment: You should print out Session["totalCost"] and have a think about why the value is not an integer. Once you fix the problem so that value IS an integer, place some checking logic in your code so you don't hit this problem again.

Answer (score 1):

If `Session["totalCost"].ToString())` is null or empty `int.parse` will throw `input string was not put correct format`

Try adding error handling or use `int.TryParse` and provice a default value

Example:

```
         if (Session["totalCost"] != "confirm")
         {
            totRevenueLabel.Text = totalRevenueInteger.ToString();

            int value = 0;
            int.TryParse(Session["totalCost"].ToString(), out value);

            totalRevenueInteger += value;
         }
```

or

```
         if (Session["totalCost"] != "confirm")
         {
            totRevenueLabel.Text = totalRevenueInteger.ToString();

            string value = Session["totalCost"].ToString();

            totalRevenueInteger += !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? int.TryParse(value) : 0;
         }
```

Comment: I got it works but it add 60 everytime, i press the button :(